Listen for Xdebug in VSCode doesn't stop at breakpoint
Although Xdebug with VSCode worked fine for a long time suddenly it's no more possible to debug a PHP script in VSCode.
phpinfo() shows

ZendEngine v4.2.12 with Xdebug v3.3.2.

php.ini:
[xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.mode=debug,develop
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll

VSCode runs the extension php_debug v1.34.0.
launch.json:
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9003,
    },

and settings.json:
"explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
"workbench.editor.splitInGroupLayout": "vertical",
"php.validate.executablePath": "c:/xampp/php/php.exe",
"php.debug.executablePath": "c:/xampp/php/php.exe",
"editor.tabSize": 2,
"[python]": {

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong?


First of all -- check what php -v will say if you run in in your terminal 9run it from a folder where your PHP executable is). It could be showing some errors. 2) You have zend_extension=xdebug and zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll -- maybe it causes issues. 3) If all good there -- make a simple .php file and call xdebug_info(); there -- it's like phpinfo(); but with settings specific to Xdebug only and with some basic troubleshooting info. Post a screenshot of it (do it in a same way you are trying to debug -- a CLI or a web page.



Enable Xdebug log (xdebug.log=PATH_TO_LOG_FILE) and try to debug (restart web server before / make sure that log option is used). Then check what the log will have to say -- if it tries to connect at all, and if it does -- where and what the response is.


XDebug is working again. Problem was a hardlink from the original installation-directory to another place. By inserting a pathMapping section in launch.json the error is fixed:
"configurations": [
  {
    "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "port": 9003,
    "pathMappings": {
      "c:/xampp/htdocs/xyz": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  }
]

